# First element of a ng-repeat imbrication

Tags: angularjs

## AngularJS

How can i get first element and add class 'active' automatically .

There is 2 ng-repeat , I want get first group --> first item --> first element and add class.

```
<div class="first"  ng-repeat="group in group ">    
  <div class="second"  ng-repeat="item in items">    
     <div ng-class="{'active': selectedGame.id === prematchGame.id}"></div>  
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make `active` only the **first** element of the **first** `ng-repeat`, then try:

```
<div class="first" ng-repeat="group in groups">    
  <div class="second" ng-repeat="item in items">    
    <div ng-class='{active: $first && $parent.$first}'>{{item.data}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7wp2t38a/)**

Comment: Sorry , one question also about this element ... whats the best way to trigger a click in this element ??

Comment: You want to know when the first element of the first ng-repeat is clicked?

Comment: No i want to find first element , and click automatically this element

Comment: I don't understand the concept of "click automatically this element", why don't you simply call a function on this element?

Comment: I guess it should be [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)... :)

Comment: done . 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41486469/trigger-a-click-on-a-element-onload

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```
<div ng-class='{active:$first}' > {{item.data}}</div>
```

Comment: its not working , i want to get  first group --> first item --> first element only

Comment: As Mistalis post, you can use `$parent`.

Answer (score 0):

Use $first to do check for the first element of ng-repeat : [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/suzo/9Ymvt/5309/)

```
<div class="first"  ng-repeat="group in group" ng-init="firstGroup = $first">    
  <div class="second"  ng-repeat="item in items">    
     <div ng-class="{'active': selectedGame.id === prematchGame.id}"  ng-class='{active: $first && firstGroup}'></div>  
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: its not working , i want to get  first group --> first item --> first element only

Comment: In this way every element of first items has class 'acitve'

for example:  1 group -->  3 items --> 5 elements , in this way 3 elements has active class ,but i want only one and first

Comment: Yeah, got it. Please try my updated answer now and let me know if that is what you are expecting

Comment: @AroTonoyan Check the fiddle I've added above.

Answer (score 0):

simple way if all you want is first element

```
<div class="first"  ng-repeat="group in group">    
  <div class="second"  ng-repeat="item in items">    
     <div ng-class="{'active': $index == 1}" ></div>  
  </div>
 </div>
```

you can do same for other ng-repeat all will have different $index