# Trigger a click on a element onload

Tags: javascript, angularjs

## Angular.js

How can i trigger a click on a first group ---> first item ---> first '.preamatchGame' element

```
<div class="first" ng-repeat="group in groups"> 
  <div class="second" ng-repeat="item in items">    
    <div ng-class='{active: $first && $parent.$first}'>
      <div class="prematchGame" ng-click="selectGame(prematchGame.id)"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Triggering a click is not so much of the angular spirit

Comment: i need do it for $first element ,after ng-repeat